# XSLT - add whitespace after certain node in mixed content

Tags: xslt, whitespace

I can't figure out how to add whitespace in my mixed content node while maintaining the order of my content.

My XML looks like this:

```
<paragraph>
    <p>
        <keyword>First keyword</keyword>First text.
        <author>First author</author>
        <keyword>Second keyword</keyword>Second text.
        <author>Second author</author>
        <keyword>Third keyword</keyword>Third text.
        <author>Third author</author>
    </p>
</paragraph>
```

My template:

```
<xsl:template match="p" mode="readContentW">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

My output right now:

```
<phrase>First keywordFirst text. First authorSecond keywordSecond Text. Second authorThird keywordThird text. Third author</phrase>
```

What I want as output:

```
<phrase>First keyword First text. First author Second keyword Second Text. Second author Third keyword Third text. Third author</phrase>
```

Or even better something like this:

```
<phrase>
    <b>First keyword</b> First text. <i>First author</i>
    <b>Second keyword</b> Second Text. <i>Second author</i>
    <b>Third keyword</b> Third text. <i>Third author</i>
</phrase>
```

But I need that whitespace after the keyword and before the author.

I've tried manually adding whitespace via `<xsl:text> </xsl:text>` after my `<phrase>` node but I have no idea how to do that while still maintaining the order of my content.
The XML could have any number of phrase/text/author combinations so by adding the whitespace manually I'd have to put the puzzle together again, but how so without any kind of loop?

Answer (score 0):

If you transform the elements and add the space when creating text output then inserting the space is easy:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <phrase>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </phrase>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="keyword">
        <b>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </b>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="author">
        <i>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </i>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p/text()[preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::keyword]]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', .)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

You will need to explain a bit more why or when the line break at the end of `First text.` is converted to a space to allow us to implement that as a template.

Comment: The space after keyword is working, thanks. The <b> and <i> tags, however, are not. I'm using the exact templates you gave me. The only difference is that my stylesheet (wasn't created by me) doesn't use the identity transform but the opposite [ <xsl:template match="*"/> ]. But I don't think that's the problem. As to your question, I honestly can't tell you why the line break is converted to a space. I'm not adding that space explicitly.

Comment: Well `<xsl:template match="*"/>` suppresses processing of any elements and their contents so you won't get far in a stylesheet doing that. The complete sample I posted is at http://xsltransform.net/ej9EGcr, as you can see, the transformation to `b` and `i` is done there fine. If you only want to transform certain elements and skip others, but process the contents, then the template for `match="*"` should use `<xsl:apply-templates/>`, to make sure any child nodes are processed by more specialized templates if they exist.